# How to get http api request logs from influxdb2 running in docker container

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2

There are docs for this in v1.8, but I can't find any for v2+

> https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/administration/logs/

I'm trying to diagnose an issue where a client suddenly started returning an error when writing data to influx:

> Last sent query failed. HTTPcode 400

The client isn't logging any more details, and I can't change it, so I need the error details from influx.

I was able to get some logs, but they don't contain any http request info. They look like this:

```
ts=2022-07-16T17:18:57.209420Z lvl=info msg="Snapshot for path written" log_id=0bZ5ZWkl000 service=storage-engine engine=tsm1 op_name=tsm1_cache_snapshot path=/var/lib/influxdb2/engine/data/225f097804ddae07/autogen/21 duration=8.754ms
ts=2022-07-16T17:18:57.209477Z lvl=info msg="Cache snapshot (end)" log_id=0bZ5ZWkl000 service=storage-engine engine=tsm1 op_name=tsm1_cache_snapshot op_event=end op_elapsed=8.760ms
ts=2022-07-16T17:19:52.295450Z lvl=info msg="Retention policy deletion check (start)" log_id=0bZ5ZWkl000 service=retention op_name=retention_delete_check op_event=start
ts=2022-07-16T17:19:52.295781Z lvl=info msg="Retention policy deletion check (end)" log_id=0bZ5ZWkl000 service=retention op_name=retention_delete_check op_event=end op_elapsed=0.434ms
```

I'm looking for a file to cat, or even a config option I can add to a docker-compose file to enable http logging?